# HOw to merge lines with awk to one line with same key

Tags: awk

I have following file

```
 lion : catty : mouse
 lion : cat   : bear
 rubber: ham  : cheese
```

I would like to merge each line with the key (= first field) to

```
lion : catty : mouse ; cat : bear
rubber: ham : cheese
```

I have done this with awk this way, but it does not work.

```
  #!/usr/bin/awk -f
  BEGIN {FS=":"} 
  a[$1]=a[$1] ";" $2 " : " $3
  END{
  for (x in a) print x,a[x]}
```

I would be thanksful if some awk jack could tell me what I do wrong.
thanks

Comment: Do you REALLY have blank chars at the start of each input line and before/after some of the `:`s? If not then please tidy up your example to reflect reality as what the input looks like obviously makes a big difference to the tool you need to parse that input.

Comment: Post a new question and link this question to it. Don't post images, post sample data with the expected output.

Comment: @JamesBrown I have done so, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk -F' *: *' -v OFS=' : ' '{a[$1] = ($1 in a ? a[$1] " ; " : "") $2 OFS $3} END{for (key in a) print key, a[key]}' file
rubber : ham : cheese
lion : catty : mouse ; cat : bear
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on command line as a one-liner. But when I write it as script I get `syntax error  at the for (x in a)` Why?

Comment: I'm guessing you introduced a syntax error when you copy/pasted it? Without seeing the code that's the best I can do to help debug the code.

Comment: I discoverted that the END in the script must be before the { - now it works also as awk script . THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk -F: '{a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]?";":":") $2":" $3} END{for (x in a) print x,a[x]}' file
  lion  : catty : mouse; cat   : bear
  rubber : ham  : cheese
```

If you want prettier output, try:

```
$ awk -F: '{a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]?" ; ":" : ") $2" : " $3} END{for (x in a) print x,a[x]}' file | column -t
lion    :  catty  :  mouse   ;  cat  :  bear
rubber  :  ham    :  cheese
```